# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

I have the following Code in Json :

```
function GetCRByCRNO(CRNO) {
var params = { "CRNO": CRNO };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: AppCOJS.getBaseURL() + '/hcis/license-services/SE.TCC.CLU.Services.LicenseRequest.LicenseRequest.svc/GetCRByCRNO',
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    complete: GetCRByCRNOCompleted
});
```

When I try to execute the code by asp.net I had the error:

> "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
>   Failed to load '

Please advice me ...

Regards.

Comment: Try with set datatype like this `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: might help [there is the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574867/networkerror-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-ajax-webapi)